# Tally Javascript object property values

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have several objects inside of an array in Javascript. The object looks like this:

```
        model: [
            {
                category: 'Media',
                value: '',
                checked: false
            },
            {
                category: 'Entertainment',
                value: '',
                checked: false
            },
            {
                category: 'Music',
                value: '',
                checked: false
            },
            {
                category: 'Theater',
                value: '',
                checked: false
            }
        ]
```

I want to loop through this array of objects, and tally up the number of `checked: true` values there are. If all of them equal `true`, I want to run a function. How do I go about seeing if all of the `checked` values are equal to `true`?

Comment: Checking if all of them are true the ES6 way: `model.every(a=>a.checked)`.

Comment: @Xufox, or `model.every(function (item) { return item.checked })`  for non-ES6 browsers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to use [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
var aggregate = function (arr) {
    return arr.reduce(function (p, c) {
        return c.checked ? p + 1 : p;
    }, 0);
}

if (aggregate(model) === model.length) {
    // call your function
}
```

**edit**

As pointed out by [@Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi), it's faster to use the [`Array.prototype.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Every) solution from [the comments above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30315246/tally-javascript-object-property-values/30315256#comment48725982_30315246), since `.every` terminates on the first instance the callback returns `false`:

```
var allChecked = function (arr) {
    return arr.every(function (item) {
        return item.checked;
    });
}

if (allChecked(model)) {
    // call your function
}
```

Although, if you're after performance, it's even faster to use a for-loop:

```
var allChecked = function (arr) {
    for (var i = arr.length; --i;)
        if (!arr[i].checked) return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Ouch, no. Not the easiest for sure (and not performant either). Why not use `.every` as you already suggested in the comments?

Comment: @Bergi `.reduce` has the effect of returning the number of items where `item.checked === true`, instead of just a binary true/false, which could be of use to the OP

Comment: OP did not mention counting? Yes, if he needs the number, then one would use `reduce`, but to determine "*whether all of them equal `true`*",  `every`is the appropriate tool.

Comment: @Bergi also added a for-loop solution, since that yields the best performance

Comment: @royhowie for-loop is faster for now.  `every()` is still kind of new and likely to be optimized at some point

Answer (score 1):

As Xufox and royhowie suggested, [every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) is the optimum choice:

```
obj.model.every(val=>val.checked); // ES6
obj.model.every(function(val){ return val.checked; }); //ES5.1+
```

If you wanted to play with prototypes:

```
Array.prototype.countWhenField = function(field){this._field=field; return this};
Array.prototype.isEqualTo = function(val){
    var arr = this,
        fld = this._field;

    // using reduce() here as an example, but can use every()
    return arr.reduce(function (prev, curr) {
        return curr[fld] == val ? prev + 1 : prev;
    },0);
};

var obj = { 
  model : [
            {
                category: 'Media',
                value: '',
                checked: true
            },
            {
                category: 'Entertainment',
                value: '',
                checked: true
            },
            {
                category: 'Music',
                value: '',
                checked: false
            },
            {
                category: 'Theater',
                value: '',
                checked: true
            }
          ]
};

console.log(
  obj.model.countWhenField('checked').isEqualTo(true), // 3
  obj.model.length                                     // 4
);
```

Advice is to stay away from prototypes for various reasons (especially don't prototype the base Object or Array class).  The above is a *horrible* example and should ***not by any means*** be used in production code (too many issues to point out in a short time).

It is important to note that the above is only a quick example to demonstrate how you can make something more *english* (e.g., `arr.countWhenField('checked').isEqualTo(true) == arr.length`).